# All of the .json files in one line

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, server

In my .json file all the details are in one line. How do I make it look good and placing it on different lines

[image]

Comment: "*How do I make it look good and placing it on different lines*" Some linebreaks, perhaps? Not sure if/how the formatting of a JSON file is really that on-topic here. [ask]

Comment: how did you make said file?

Comment: FYI: for some JSON parsers, as well as for bandwidth, the non-"beautify" version is probably more performant...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can format your JSON document using `Shift+Alt+F` or `Format Document` from the context menu.

There are also extensions available in the Marketplace (e.g. [Prettier - Code formatter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode)).

Answer (score -1):

If you want to beatify your json file, you can search an extension on the marketplace